# Iterating WCHARs in a Rich Edit contol

Tags: winapi, utf-16, richedit

I am working with a Rich Edit control, and would like to iterate the `WCHAR` values in it.

I have written this routine:

```cpp
int GetCharacterAtIndex(int pos) const
{
    TEXTRANGE tr{};
    tr.chrg.cpMin = pos;
    tr.chrg.cpMax = pos + 1;
    WCHAR buffer[2]{};
    tr.lpstrText = buffer;
    DWORD charsRetrieved = SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_GETTEXTRANGE, 0, (LPARAM)&tr);
    assert(charsRetrieved < DIM(buffer));
    if (charsRetrieved <= 0) return -1;
    return buffer[0];
}
```

This works great as long as the character at `pos` is not part of a UTF-16 surrogate pair. However, if it *is* part of a surrogate pair, the value returned is always the low surrogate. This is doubly annoying because the value returned in `charsRetrieved` is still just 1.

I modified the code as follows to get the high surrogates using `EM_GETSELTEXT`:

```cpp
int GetCharacterAtIndex(int pos) const
{
    TEXTRANGE tr{};
    tr.chrg.cpMin = pos;
    tr.chrg.cpMax = pos + 1;
    WCHAR buffer[10]{}; // add some extra space
    tr.lpstrText = buffer;
    DWORD charsRetrieved = SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_GETTEXTRANGE, 0, (LPARAM)&tr);
    assert(charsRetrieved < DIM(buffer));
    if (charsRetrieved <= 0) return -1;
    int index = 0;
    if (buffer[0] >= 0xD800 && buffer[0] < 0xDC00)
    {
        SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_SETSEL, pos, pos + 1);
        DWORD surrogateStart{}, surrogateEnd{};
        SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_GETSEL, (WPARAM)&surrogateStart, (LPARAM)&surrogateEnd);
        if (surrogateStart == surrogateEnd)
        {
            // this may be a WinAPI bug. When pos actually points to the low surrogate, you sometimes have to do this twice.
            SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_SETSEL, pos, pos + 1);
            SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_GETSEL, (WPARAM)&surrogateStart, (LPARAM)&surrogateEnd);
        }
        LRESULT gotChars = SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_GETSELTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)buffer);
        assert(gotChars < DIM(buffer));
        if (gotChars <= 0) return -1;
        index = pos - surrogateStart;
        assert(index < gotChars);
    }
    return buffer[index];
}
```

This works, but it relies on `EM_GETSELTEXT`. The problem with `EM_GETSELTEXT` is that it requires mucking with the selection. This causes visual artifacts, even if you suppress redraw. And it leads to potentially even messier code to suppress selection change notifications (or not), and it requires the caller to save and restore the selection if required.

The bottom line is that it is very slow and it creates ugly visual artifacts.

Have I missed a more elegant way to accomplish this?

`EM_GETTEXTRANGE` is fast, silent, and self-contained. I would really like not to have to use `EM_GETSELTEXT`.

Comment: Hard to see how this happened.  The code allows only one WCHAR to be returned, so logically that will be the low surrogate.  At which point you could simply call EM_GETTEXTRANGE again to get two.  I suspect this came around because the *pos* argument really ought to be passed by reference.  So the caller knows how to index the text correctly.

Comment: Suppose there is exactly one surrogate pair character on the control; the low surrogate is at index 0 and the high surrogate at index 1. What's happening is that when the input to my function is 1, EM_GETTEXTRANGE nevertheless returns the WCHAR at 0. There appears to be no way to know if the surrogate pair starts at 0 or 1.

Comment: You are asking EM_GETTEXTRANGE for only 1 WCHAR at a time. Have you tried asking it for more than 1 at a time, and then discard any chars you don't need?

Comment: I have tried asking for more than one character at a time, but the issue remains. There seems to be no way to know if the surrogate pair starts at `pos` or `pos - 1`.

Comment: Sure there is. UTF-16 is designed to let you determine if a char is a low or high surrogate. You already know that. If you retrieve 2 chars and the 1st one is high, then you know you have to go back 1 to get the low. If the 1st char is low, then you already have the high if present

Comment: >If you retrieve 2 chars and the 1st one is high.

But the problem is, if I ask for the character at the position of the high surrogate, I nevertheless get the character starting with the low surrogate. So whether I ask for 0 or 1 (in the example above), I always get the character starting at zero. In the general case, I do not know whether the buffer I got back reflects the character sequence at `pos` or `pos - 1`.

Comment: This is why I put emphasis on passing *pos* by reference.  Do that right (increment by 1 for a regular codepoint, by 2 for a surrogate) and the caller will never land on a high surrogate.

Comment: This program is an API in a class framework that supports an embedded Lua plugin. Lua does not pass numbers by reference, so that's right out. It would have to be an awkward interface that returns two values. I haven't ruled it out, but the problem is that even then, I still have the problem that for an arbitary call I don't know whether the sequence starts at `pos` or `pos - 1`. There's no way to guarantee the iteration starts with 0 unless I completely change the API. (Also not out of the realm of possibility.)

Comment: On further reflection, I think Hans Passant's solution is best: change the API interface. Now instead of returning `int` it should return `std::wstring` containing the complete Unicode codepoint in UTF16 format. Then callers will increment their index variable based on the `size` of the returned strings. If Han wants to write it up as an answer I will click it. Otherwise I'll do it myself when I can.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and show what I did in an answer, fwiw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on helpful comments on my original question, I think the best solution is to modify the API so that it always returns a complete Unicode character in a `std::wstring`. The caller can then use the `size` method on the return value to increment the iterator if required.

Also, I corrected my terminology from the question. The high surrogate comes first. (In my question, I had the terminology backwards.)

```cpp
std::wstring GetCharacterAtIndex(int pos) const
{
    TEXTRANGE tr{};
    tr.chrg.cpMin = pos;
    tr.chrg.cpMax = pos + 2; // in case it's a surrogate pair
    std::wstring buffer(10, 0); // extra space 
    tr.lpstrText = buffer.data();
    DWORD charsRetrieved = SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_GETTEXTRANGE, 0, (LPARAM)&tr);
    assert(charsRetrieved < buffer.size());
    if (charsRetrieved <= 0) return L"";
    // EM_GETTEXTRANGE always returns the start of a full surrogate pair, even if pos points to a low surrogate.
    if (buffer[0] < 0xD800 || buffer[0] >= 0xDC00) // when buffer[0] is not a surrogate
        charsRetrieved = 1;
    buffer.resize(charsRetrieved);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest getting rid of the `pos+1` query altogether and just use the `pos+2` query by itself. If it returns a complete surrogate, you can return the whole pair. If the 1st char is not a surrogate then simply ignore the 2nd char. You should also be using `charsRetrieved` when returning `buffer` so you don't have to rely on the null terminator.

Comment: Good ideas, both. I have revised it.

Comment: Minor nitpick: you didn't need to change `buffer` to `std::wstring`, you could have left it as a `WCHAR[]` and just paid attention to `charsRetrieved` when returning a `std::wstring`, eg: `WCHAR buffer[3]{}; ... return std::wstring(buffer, charsRetrieved);` I would also suggest `if (buffer[0] < 0xD800 || buffer[0] > 0xDFFF)` when `buffer[0]` is not a surrogate

Comment: I have been moving away from stack arrays of chars in favor of std::string. It's mostly just a style preference, I admit. Where it really saved my bacon was in some inherited code that had hard-coded a "really big buffer" of 5000 bytes, and then I made a change that blew that number out of the water. I have since been converting to std::string as the opportunity arises. ymmv.